# How to order levels in a variable based on both the sum of value in a variable and the levels in another variable?

Tags: r, sorting, r-factor

I have a data frame looking like this that I'm preparing for a ggplot:

```
txt <- "v1 v2 v3
'Strongly agree' 83.1 var1
'Agree' 14.9 var1
'Disagree' 1.5 var1
'Strongly disagree' 0.6 var1
'Strongly agree' 11.8 var2
'Agree' 36.5 var2
'Disagree' 17.7 var2
'Strongly disagree' 43.8 var2
'Strongly agree' 19.6 var3
'Agree' 12 var3
'Disagree' 31.6 var3
'Strongly disagree' 36.8 var3"

mydata <- read.table(textConnection(txt), sep = " ", header = TRUE)
```

My question is: How to order the levels in `mydata$v3` based on both the value in `mydta$v2` and the levels in `mydata$v1`?

An example: If I for instance would like to order the levels in `mydata$v3` based on the highest value in `mydata$v2` within the level 'Strongly agree' in `mydata$v1` the order i would get would be: `var1`, `var3`, `var2` because the values in `mydata$v2` is 83.1, 19.6, 11.8.

Another example: if I for instance would like to order the levels in `mydata$v3` based on the sum of values in `mydata$v2` within the levels 'Strongly agree' and 'Agree' in `mydata$v1` the order I would get would be: `var1`, `var2`, `var3` because the values in `mydata$v2` is (83.1+14.9)=98, (11.8+36.5)=48.3, (19.6+12)=31.6

I have no idea how to approach this myself. And also, I deal with a lot of frames like this so the code have to go into a function

**EDIT:**

In both examples, the result I'm going for is the original data.frame ONLY with the order in levels in mydata$v3 changed.

So in example 1 I have:

```
                  v1   v2   v3
1     Strongly agree 83.1 var1
2              Agree 14.9 var1
3           Disagree  1.5 var1
4  Strongly disagree  0.6 var1
5     Strongly agree 11.8 var2
6              Agree 36.5 var2
7           Disagree 17.7 var2
8  Strongly disagree 43.8 var2
9     Strongly agree 19.6 var3
10             Agree 12.0 var3
11          Disagree 31.6 var3
12 Strongly disagree 36.8 var3 

levels(mydata$v3)
[1] "var1" "var2" "var3"
```

but what I want to end out with is this.

```
                  v1   v2   v3
1     Strongly agree 83.1 var1
2              Agree 14.9 var1
3           Disagree  1.5 var1
4  Strongly disagree  0.6 var1
5     Strongly agree 11.8 var2
6              Agree 36.5 var2
7           Disagree 17.7 var2
8  Strongly disagree 43.8 var2
9     Strongly agree 19.6 var3
10             Agree 12.0 var3
11          Disagree 31.6 var3
12 Strongly disagree 36.8 var3 

levels(mydata$v3)
[1] "var1" "var3" "var2"
```

In example two I have:

```
                  v1   v2   v3
1     Strongly agree 83.1 var1
2              Agree 14.9 var1
3           Disagree  1.5 var1
4  Strongly disagree  0.6 var1
5     Strongly agree 11.8 var2
6              Agree 36.5 var2
7           Disagree 17.7 var2
8  Strongly disagree 43.8 var2
9     Strongly agree 19.6 var3
10             Agree 12.0 var3
11          Disagree 31.6 var3
12 Strongly disagree 36.8 var3 

levels(mydata$v3)
[1] "var1" "var2" "var3"
```

but want:

```
                  v1   v2   v3
1     Strongly agree 83.1 var1
2              Agree 14.9 var1
3           Disagree  1.5 var1
4  Strongly disagree  0.6 var1
5     Strongly agree 11.8 var2
6              Agree 36.5 var2
7           Disagree 17.7 var2
8  Strongly disagree 43.8 var2
9     Strongly agree 19.6 var3
10             Agree 12.0 var3
11          Disagree 31.6 var3
12 Strongly disagree 36.8 var3 

levels(mydata$v3)
[1] "var1" "var2" "var3"
```

Notice, that in example two what I have and what i want is identical, but I have a lot of data.frames in which this will not be the case.

What I'm looking for I guess, is a complex version of

```
factor(maydata$v3, levels(mydata$v3)[EXAMPLE1: order after value in v2 within 1 level in v1 /EXAMPLE2: order after sum of value within 2 levels in v1])
```

Comment: Order of what, levels within a factor?

Comment: Yes I need to order the levels within the factor mydata$v3.

Comment: Sorry if the question is a bit cryptic, I tried to be as specific as I could

Comment: But now, for the first example, the values for "Strongly agree" are not ordered: v2 is 83.1, 11.8, 19.6 and v3 is var1, var2, var3 instead  of var1, var3, var2.

Comment: No the values are not ordered, and I don't think the need be in the end. it's for a stacked barplot in ggplot2, so I want the original order of v2 and v1. the levels in v3 is my x-variable in ggplot, so yes it has the order var1, var2, var3. And what i would like for that to change accordingly to the values in v2 (from highest value to lowest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with `aggregate`:

```
f <- function(mydata, v1.val) {
  # Value or sum of v2 within the selected rows
  sums <- aggregate(v2 ~ v3, data=mydata[mydata$v1 %in% v1.val,], FUN=sum)

  # Decreasing order of the sum of v2 values, or the only v2 value, for each level of v3
  ord <- order(sums$v2, decreasing=TRUE)

  # Build a new factor with the proper levels and assign it to v3
  fac <- factor(mydata$v3, levels=sums$v3[ord])

  mydata$v3 <- fac
  return(mydata)
}
```

The data frames look as above, but the factor levels are as desired:

```
> f(mydata, 'Strongly agree')$v3
 [1] var1 var1 var1 var1 var2 var2 var2 var2 var3 var3 var3 var3
Levels: var1 var3 var2

> f(mydata, c('Strongly agree', 'Agree'))$v3
 [1] var1 var1 var1 var1 var2 var2 var2 var2 var3 var3 var3 var3
Levels: var1 var2 var3
```